# ¿Estoy generando código para VB.Net que crea una base y sus objetos. Qué pasa si borro los GO?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

La cadena que contiene el código lo genero seleccionando el objeto y luego la opción CREATE TO, de SQL Server Management Studio, eso genera un código en el que le inserta varios comandos GO. Pero como lo estoy trascribiendo para VB.Net creo que esos GO son innecesarios o ¿tendrán algún efecto en el código de VB.Net?

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo que podamos ver? Ya buscaste qué hace la sentencia GO?